# next() call in express-ws module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I came across a sample code for my webserver using express-ws for reliable Websocket connection between my server and client browser. The code will start listening in port 3000 for websocket connection.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('middleware');
    req.testing = 'testing';
    return next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('get route', req.testing);
  res.end();
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
  console.log('socket', req.testing);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

what is the use of next() API in express-websocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It calls the next `middleware` in the stack.

Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:

- Execute any code.
- Make changes to the request and the response objects.
- End the request-response cycle.
- Call the next middleware in the stack.

If the current middleware function does not end the request-response
   cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware
   function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.
[image: explanation]
**Example** A simple `hello world` example using express and later we will define middleware function.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

**Middleware function**

```
var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED');
  next();
}
```

**Notice the call above to `next()`. Calling this function invokes the next middleware function in the app. The `next()` function is not a part of the `Node.js` or `Express API`, but is the third argument that is passed to the middleware function. The `next()` function could be named anything, but by convention it is always named `“next”`. To avoid confusion, always use this convention.**

To load the middleware function, call app.use(), specifying the middleware function. For example, the following code loads the myLogger middleware function before the route to the root path (/).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED');
  next();
}
app.use(myLogger);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Every time the app receives a request, it prints the message “LOGGED” to the terminal.

The order of middleware loading is important: middleware functions that are loaded first are also executed first.

If myLogger is loaded after the route to the root path, the request never reaches it and the app doesn’t print “LOGGED”, because the route handler of the root path terminates the request-response cycle.

The middleware function myLogger simply prints a message, then passes on the request to the next middleware function in the stack by calling the `next()` function.

[Source Expressjs guide article](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Comment: Hi, does middleware get called for every websocket request or just during initial handshake when connection is being established ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to write middleware for use in express apps follow this guide

[Writing middleware for use in express apps](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)